# Access safari bookmarks in macOS Mojave programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, safari, macos-mojave

Since upgraded to macOS Mojave, I find there are permission restrictions to user from accessing `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist`. So is there an alternative way to do it programmatically? Is there a `SafariKit` or something I can use to import bookmarks to my own program? I tried to search online, but no one mentions anything about it. If you guys know, please help me. Thank you

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11974097/2227743

Comment: I don't think this would work. First of all, the project I'm writing is not sandboxed. Second, I can't even try to read it in terminal through vim or cat. I'm trying to find a more"official" way of doing it

Comment: If not sandboxed, then you just have to add the app to System Preferences > Security > Confidentiality > Disk access. And if you add Terminal.app there you will be able to access ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist again with cat/vim/...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll give it a try

Comment: @Moritz Hello, I have tried the way you described, it works perfectly. Thank you. Maybe you can properly answer this question, then I will set it to the correct answer. It may be helpful for others too

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist anymore because of the stricter security rules in Mojave.

I don't think there's an API to do this specific action yet, so the solution for now is to add the application yourself to `System Preferences > Security > Confidentiality > Disk access`.

For example if you add Terminal.app to this Confidentiality subgroup, this will grant access to the whole disk to all commands executed in Terminal, inluding using cat/vim/... to access ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist.